# How to get assertion value using groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have one test step which contains two assertion.

- Not SOAP Fault
- Contains. The Condition is that response should contain "Message Sent Successfully"

Now I have one groovy script, from where I am executing this test step. Using this groovy script I need to print assertion name, Value and Status. Below is the code I have written:

```
testStepSrc = testCase.getTestStepByName(testName)
Assertioncounter = testStepSrc.getAssertionList().size()
for (AssertionCount in 0..Assertioncounter-1)
{
log.info("Assertion :" + testStepSrc.getAssertionAt(AssertionCount).getName() + " :: " + testStepSrc.getAssertionAt(AssertionCount).getStatus())

error = testStepSrc.getAssertionAt(AssertionCount).getErrors()
if (error != null)
   {
    log.error(error[0].getMessage())
   }
 }
```

but in output it is displaying like:

```
Wed Sep 04 17:21:11 IST 2013:INFO:Assertion :Not SOAP Fault :: VALID
Wed Sep 04 17:21:11 IST 2013:INFO:Assertion :Contains :: VALID
```

As you can see, I am able to print assertion name and status but not the value of 'Contains' assertion. Please help me how to get the value of a particular assertion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So here is some things for you to read

- http://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=359
- http://whathaveyoutried.com

and what i tried

```
def assertionsList = testRunner.getTestCase().getTestStepByName("Test Step Name").getAssertionList()
for( e in assertionsList){
    log.info e.getToken() //gives the value of the content to search for
    log.info e.DESCRIPTION
    log.info e.ID
    log.info e.LABEL
    log.info e.toString()
}
```

This gives the following output

```
Wed Sep 04 15:12:19 ADT 2013:INFO:Abhishek //the contains assertion was checking for the word "Abhishek" in the response of my test step where the assertion was applied.
Wed Sep 04 15:12:19 ADT 2013:INFO:Searches for the existence of a string token in the property value, supports regular expressions. Applicable to any property. 
Wed Sep 04 15:12:19 ADT 2013:INFO:Simple Contains
Wed Sep 04 15:12:19 ADT 2013:INFO:Contains
Wed Sep 04 15:12:19 ADT 2013:INFO:com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.assertions.basic.SimpleContainsAssertion@c4115f0
```

Comment: you didn't get my question Abhishek. I want to print the condition of 'Contains' assertion. that means I want to Print "Message sent successfully". I tried all this above stuff, but I am not able to print. So, before suggesting me "whatyouhavetried.com", read the whole question fully and understand the requirement. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Alright, I am confused. does your contains assertion check for the presence of "Message sent Successfully" in the response of Test Step where the assertion has been applied or you want to print the message "Message sent successfully" when the contains assertion is successful?

Comment: gettoken is not supported... do u have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Abhishek's response did contain you answer I believe but just not in the format you were looking for.

I was looking for the same info for custom reporting and after digging through The SoapUI forms I stumbled upon this.

The piece of code that I believe you are looking for is:

```
log.info e.getToken()
```

however this is an example of how to retrieve it only when an error occurs but you can get it in a valid scenario using something similar to:

```
def iAssertionName = assertionNameList[j]
def iAssertionStatus = testStep.getAssertionAt(j).getStatus().toString()
def tstep = testStep.getName()
def gStatus =  testStep.getAssertionAt(j).status
def expect = testStep.getAssertionAt(j).getToken()
log.info "Expected Content: " + expect
```

This is a subset of my code but produces the log message:

```
Fri Sep 20 11:04:09 CDT 2013:INFO:Expected Content: success
```

My SoapUI script assertion was checking to see if my response contained the string "success".

Thanks Abhishek for your response!